# Rendering MongoDB documents with Meteor

Tags: meteor

The question is: how to display complex documents returned from Mongodb.

Suppose I have two projects in my Projects collection and each project has 2 People embedded by their IDs from the People collection.
Project.find() returns this CURSOR which I'm presenting as JSON for readability:

```
{ "_id" : "5ed5ade8-c140-46f7-8d9e-2344fc53df8e",  "name" : "Project1", "personnel" : [ "b4690c4b-d126-4737-8f40-921234567890", "977a6335-a1be-4af5-8b3f-4abcdefghijk" ] }
{ "_id" : "23f073c7-a713-4713-86a7-7d6600433146", "name" : "Project2", "personnel" : [ "b4690c4b-d126-4737-8f40-92b43072d7a1", "977a6335-a1be-4af5-8b3f-48cd5f8328db" ]}
```

My template in .html file:

```
<template name="theProjects">
     {{#each theTitles}}
          Name: {{name}}
          Personnel: {{personnel}}
     {{/each}}
</template>
```

renders this in the browser:

> Name: Project1
>
> > Personnel: b4690c4b-d126-4737-8f40-921234567890,977a6335-a1be-4af5-8b3f-4abcdefghijk
>
> Name: Project2
>
> > Personnel:b4690c4b-d126-4737-8f40-92b43072d7a1,977a6335-a1be-4af5-8b3f-48cd5f8328db

Questions:

1. The {{personnel}} field is simply being filled in by the contents of the personnel array in the Projects collect. I want to list these separately on their own line. Can't figure that out. Just slicing won't do because...
2. The greater need clearly is to be able to manipulate and edit the Personnel data so the template has to be properly Meteor reactive.
3. Now the hard one: the personnel ID's from the People collection are embedded in the Project documents. How would I use Meteor to replace the ID's with the appropriate names from the Personnel collection and still keep their data reactivity?

I know this is a lot to ask but these kind of things seem like they are foundational to bigger and more complex web site.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/3220991

This is a gist I made to show you use the of Handlebars helpers. This will stay reactive and is very easy to use. I hope you can use it.

If you need more help or comments , just mention me.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm getting a javascript error that 'context' is undefined on the _for_ line.

Comment: @LarryRobbins could you make a gist of your implementation ? Make sure    to pass the right parameter to the print function .

Comment: My total stupidity. Some of my Projects had no Personnel as yet so were coming back undefined. Your solution works perfectly. Thank you!!