# meteor parse nested mongo collection in template

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am working on a project in meteor which has a mongo collection.

Let's call this collection "A".

Documents in "A" are of the following structure:

```
{ id:"XXX", name:"YYY", array: { "1": text1, "2": text2 } }
```

I also have a template to show this kind of document inside my html:

```
<input type="text" name={{name}} value={{array.$1}} />
```

The value in array.1 is not presented. My question is how do I present this value?

I've been googling it for a long time now, found nothing useful but this:  [Rendering MongoDB documents with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746006/rendering-mongodb-documents-with-meteor)

Which didn't really help. Also meteor documentation doesn't seem to have information about this kind of usage.

Comment: Defining a helper function was needed: 

    Template.<templateName>.helpers:
        'array1' -> 
            A.findOne({_id:@_id}).array[1]

Then inside the html just call the function: 

    {{array1}}

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you wanted to use '$' sign? In JS it doesn't mean anything special.

For example:

```
var array = {"1": "text1", "2":"text2"};
console.log(array.$1);
```

Comes back with "undefined".

And this name "array" is confusing because its prototype is not equal to Array.prototype

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(array) === Array.prototype
```

comes back with "false".

The following code should work.

```
<input type="text" name={{name}} value={{array['1']}} />
```

Also check this out: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)